# React - state like list is losing value

Tags: reactjs, state, setstate

My problem is this ... I am using a form, however, when I change from one field to another, the value referring to the state of the previous field is lost. With that, at the end of the filling, only the last field of the state is filled.
I solved the problem by including a local variable in onSubmit with the fields filled in, but from what I understand so far, the best practice would be to use state.
Could someone help me and tell me what I am failing to do? Thank you very much.

```
class AddItem extends React.Component {
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {validated: false};
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            item: {
            titulo: '',
            descricao: '',
            estado: '',
            cidade: null,
            usuario: 1,
            data: new Date(),
            }
        }
    }  
  
    handleSubmit (event) {

        const form = event.currentTarget;
        console.log(item);

        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }else{
            api(this.state.item);
            event.preventDefault();
      }
      this.setState({validated: true});
    };

    handleChange (event) {
        let name = event.target.name;
        let value = event.target.value;
        this.setState({item: {[name]: value}});
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not keeping any of the previous values in state: eg `this.setState({validated: true});` will mean that the state no longer has an `item` property.

Spread the previous state into the new state so that old properties don't get lost whenever you call `setState`:

```
this.setState({validated: true});
```

to

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, validated: true });
```

and

```
this.setState({item: {[name]: value}});
```

to

```
this.setState({ ...this.state, item: { ...this.state.item, [name]: value }} );
```

Comment: Perfect. It's working fine now. I had seen this '...' but I didin't understand very well how it works. Thank you very much for the very quick response.